# Windows 7 Update .NET Framework failure

Tags: windows-7, windows, updates, .net-framework

I have a problem updating a Windows 7 machine with KB2518870. This update is for .NET Framework 4.0. It fails! What should I do?

1. Ignore?
2. Uninstall .NET Framework and then try the update?
3. Use a better plan?

Comment: Try with a restart. Have you updated earlier and not restart the PC?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am at a relative's house trying gingerly to sort out their problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take good backups, including maybe a hard disk image, before trying my advice below.

First, try to download the patch from *[Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4](https://web.archive.org/web/20120414030720/http://www.microsoft.com:80/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26409)* and apply it this way.

If this doesn't work, you could try to repair [.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 4.0 in Control Panel / Programs and Features: Right-click on it and choose the Repair option.

If this still doesn't work, you can try uninstalling .NET 4.0.

If uninstallation doesn't work, use the [.NET Framework Cleanup Tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20160301085724/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx). Read the linked article very carefully before using this tool.

Comment: Will try the cleanup tool later today

Comment: Thank you for the cleanup tool, it removed .NET when Uninstall did not.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend you do not do a), b) is an option, but as for c)...

The most common problem for [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) updates to fail is lack of disk space, but it could be anything.

However, can you look in the [Event Viewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer) and see if anything comes up? .NET is very good at logging/telling you what is wrong.

If you do not need to look back on the log, I recommend clearing it, applying the update again and checking for any events.

Comment: Tried the logs, seem comprehensive but difficult to id problem.  Appreciate your advice on a).

Comment: @Guy Thomas - can you post a screenshot and I will try to help further.

Comment: Dear William thanks for the offer of extra help.  The cleanup tool turned out to be the solution hence I ticked the above answer.